# How to give space between two cardview in a Recyclerview

Tags: android

[I am facing problem to give space between two item of the recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfY7u.jpg)

Comment: Please share some XML, and what you've tried already.

Comment: Add padding at the xml layout of your item or using `ItemDecoration`

Comment: Add `padding` to the Root tag in the `Layout` you're inflating as a row for `RecyclerView`. You can add only `paddingBottom` as well, that will work too.

Comment: heres xml of recyclerview I tried with padding and margin : 
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/option_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="138dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp" />

Comment: thanks.problem solved .Imma newbie so facing some lol problems. :'(

Answer (score 2):

Add Padding or Margin for your item.xml of RecyclerView

Comment: thanks.problem solved .Imma newbie so facing some lol problems. :'(

Comment: It was my first question.So I messed up many things.I will add code next time.